# OptionMenu's choices are not displaying when a loop is used- tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

There is a OptionMenu and my options are not diplaying even after using **get()**
I am appending all the values in a list because I want it to load it again later in my GUI
here is my code

```
self.make_a_list=[]
self.number_row=1
def function_1(self):
    self.var=StringVar()
    options=["one","two","three","four"]
    menu1=OptionMenu(self,self.var,*options)
    menu1.config(width=10)
    menu1.grid(column=5,row=int(self.number_row))
    self.make_a_list.append(self.var)
    self.var.set("one")
    self.number_row=self.number_row+1

def function_2(self):
   for i in range(self.number_row):
       print(self.make_a_list[i].get())
```

I know I am doing something wrong But not able to figure out

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you're using? `function_2` has invalid syntax, like the semicolon after the `for` loop.

Comment: @wil93 I am sorry. I wrote that mistakenly.
I have edited my question

Comment: I didn't try it but it seems still wrong (the for syntax requires a colon at the end, and then an indentation)

Comment: Now check. Indentation was wrong too:) But now i have corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see in your code is that you're starting with `self.number_row` set to 1 (one) rather than 0 (zero). The first time you create a variable you append it to `self.make_a_list`, making it item zero (ie: self.make_a_list[0]`). Then, you increment`self.number_row` making it 2.

`function_2` does a loop over `range(self.number_row)`. If you have just one option menu, this will loop over `range(2)`,meaning 0 and 1. Since the list only has a single item you'll get an index out of range error the second time through the loop.

In python you don't need to loop over a list by index. Instead of using indexes, simple iterate over the list element by element. If you get into the habit of using lists this way, you'll never have this type of off-by-one error.

```
def function_2(self):
    for item in self.make_a_list:
        print(item.get())
```